# memory requirement for jruby +rails+mongrel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails

hi 
I am planning to run jruby (1.5.3 latest) on mongrel but how much memory will it require on x64 server for a simple web site ? and how many instances will be required ?

10000 page views per day

for the same requirement what would be the numbers for ruby.

any reference production data would be welcome.

Comment: btw, a good article analyzing ruby performance and memory usage is http://programmingzen.com/2010/07/19/the-great-ruby-shootout-july-2010/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably won't use mongrel with jruby, at least i've never heard of it.  We run an app using trinidad, which wraps tomcat7 and for similar performance to what you're looking for I use a 1gb heap.

Mongrel has really gone out of favour for more robust setups using passenger or thin or unicorn for instance.

If you're limited with memory, from my experience CRuby is the way to go.  Try REE or ruby-1.9.2 with Passenger3 and nginx.  It's a super simple setup and very fast.

JRuby definitely takes more memory, but if you have java requirements you don't have much choice.

10000 page views you should get away with a small ec2 instance (if that's what your `instances` refers to)

It's really hard to give a definitive answer though as it all depends on what type of app you're running.  is it cpu intensive calculations, or memory intensive data?? who knows

From my experience, CRuby tends to be much simpler than JRuby, easier for local use (ie tests run significantly faster in cruby) and also very fast.